# Address of local variable not within the address range of stack shown by smaps

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, gdb

I got the stack memory info of a process:

```
cat /proc/17647/smaps |grep stack

7ffff8840000-7ffff8853000 rwxp 7ffffffe9000 00:00 0                      [stack]
```

I only know `7ffff8840000-7ffff8853000` is the beginning and end boundary of the stack segment in the VM address, and the 4th column '7ffffffe9000' is the beginning RAM address of the VM address shown in the 1st column; the mapping relation is defined by the pagetable.

Here, I have 1 question: does the first byte in this VM segment has the RAM address `7ffffffe9000`? In this case, should I get a variable's VM address (for example, `x`) to  RAM address with this expression: `(x - 7ffff8840000)+ 7ffffffe9000`

I ran gdb on this process to see address of some local variable (which only can be within the stack),

```
gdb -p 17647
.....
b xx.cpp:100
....
p &var1
$2 = (int *) 0x4eb02a40
```

Here, I have a question: `var1` is a local variable in a function (which can not be wrong), but its address `0x4eb02a40` is neither in between VM address `7ffff8840000`-`7ffff8853000`,
nor is it nearby RAM address `7ffffffe9000` as `0x4eb02a40` is so much less than `7ffffffe9000`, so, is `0x4eb02a40` a VM address or a RAM address? How to get the
real RAM address of my variable?

Another question: by using both gdb and pmap or cat /proc/17647/smaps, how to judge that a variable address is in heap or stack or data segment?

Comment: Is `var1` the real name? I suspect there's a global (or at least file-scope static) variable by the same name in another file (or even a shared library) and gdb is showing you that instead.

Comment: It must be a VM address.  Why not `std::cout << (void*)&var1` in the program... avoid the issue R. discusses?  Separately, the 32-bit `0x4eb02a40` must be relative to some segment register - i.e. it could implicitly have `7ffff` (or something else) on the front, but weirdly that still couldn't fall into your map-reported range.  Does smaps report any use of memory spanning that address (i.e. not for [stack])?  I trust it's not a static local variable as that wouldn't be on the stack.

Comment: @R.I am sure var1 is a local variable.

Comment: @TonyD.there is only one line for stack info from pmap -d 17647 :00007ffff8840000      76 rwx-- 00007ffffffe9000 000:00000   [ stack ]

Comment: @TonyD.there is only one line for stack info from pmap -d 17647 :00007ffff8840000      76 rwx-- 00007ffffffe9000 000:00000   [ stack ].and i gdb the same process again(it is keep running),and p some another local variable,their address is 32bits only and quite near the address of var1,0x47cf7ea4,0x47cf7aac.....

Answer (score 0):

> var1 is a local variable in a function (which can not be wrong), but its address 0x4eb02a40 is neither in between VM address 7ffff8840000-7ffff8853000

Two possible explanations. Most likely one:

- Your program is multi-threaded, and you hit the breakpoint in thread other than main.

Each thread has its own stack region, which `libpthread.so` obtains from `mmap`. Such mappings do not have `stack` in `/proc/self/maps` -- as far as the kernel is concerned, this is just a regular anonymous mapping and there is nothing special about it.

Less likely one:

- Your program uses [coroutine-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) programming (perhaps with `makecontext`, perhaps with `longjmp`), and your breakpoint is in a coroutine that executes on a separate stack.